# SQL value pairs in multiple columns using 1 condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing trip of a bus

```
id   busid  pickup   destination
1       1    NWD      KML
2       2    KML      ORL
3       2    ORL      ULI
4       3    ULI      OIL
5       4    YUT      CDN
6       5    CDN      UYT
```

What im trying to find is when the user select pickup NWD and destination OIL.
The output will be

```
1: Take bus 1 going from NWD to KML
2: Take bus 2 going from KML to ORL
3: Take bus 2 going from ORL to ULI
4: Take bus 3 going from ULI to OIL
```

or if user select pickup NWD and destination ULI

```
1: Take bus 1 going from NWD to KML
2: Take bus 2 going from KML to ORL
3: Take bus 2 going from ORL to ULI
```

and if user select pickup YUT and destination UYT

```
1: Take bus 4 going from YUT to CDN
2: Take bus 5 going from CDN to UYT
```

So the problem is i can't get all list attached to what user select on pickup and destination. How i can get those?

Comment: You have a graph data structure and MySQL basically has no support for such data.  The one thing you can do is write  a recursive stored procedure, or think about another way of represent the problem or using a different database (Postgres, Oracle, and SQL Server, for instance, all support recursive CTEs).

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks! but what if i seperate origin from destination? do you think is it possible to get that result?

Comment: could you add some extra data to the sample? do you have extra column with something like `route_id` that show that all points belongs to some route? how is every record linked to each other? only by `pickup` and `destination` name? what if there are two or more records with same `pickup` and/or `destination` name?